# Set all divs to not allow focus

Tags: javascript, html, browser

My app works great in Chrome and IE.  But in Firefox, the divs keep getting focus.

I can go to each one and set it to have a `tabindex="-1"`, but that is a lot of divs.  It makes my code messy and eventually I am going to forget one and mess up the tab order.

**Is there a way to get Firefox to not focus on divs (like Chrome and IE11)?**

NOTE: It seems that tabindex cannot be set via CSS.

Comment: Any reason not to set the attribute via jquery?

Comment: A `div` is not an _active_ element by default so it wont get focus. If that happens for you in FF and you need to add `tabindex="-1"` to prevent this, then the problem js most likely somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jquery should be able to handle this easily:

```
$("div").attr('tabindex', -1);
```

$() returns a collection of matching elements, in this case all div's, thus the `attr` is applied to each of the items in the collection.

But `div`'s should not normally be able to be focused to begin with, so there may be a script running on your site that is doing exactly what mine is doing but inadvertently. Try removing ALL tabindex attributes from all elements that are not form elements. Additionally try a similiar jquery script to remove them;

```
$("div").removeAttr('tabindex');
```

Comment: Adding `tabindex="-1"` allows the div to be focusable, it just removes it from the tabbing order. Remove the `tabindex` attributes entirely and the elements will no longer be able to gain focus.

Comment: Obviously if the OP is asking the question there is something that he has no control of that is disturbing the norm.

Comment: I don't disagree with that, which is why I'm suggesting that you *remove* the attribute, rather than set it.

Comment: I won't put it past people to overlook the obvious, but i feel if something (library, plugin, etc) were adding tabindex to all the divs the OP would have seen this in a DOM debugger and mentioned that in the ques, but ill add removeattr to my answer anyway.